# Screen shutting off randomly

Tags: linux, ubuntu-mate

I recently wanted to get linux as my host OS which I did. After that I had some wireless adapter errors with kubuntu and switched to regular ubuntu 20.04 where my screen crashed after trying to open anything in fullscreen. After that I downgraded to 18.04 where I had the same issue. After that I switched to ubuntu MATE 20.04 where the screen shuts off randomly. In all cases, the PC didnt shut down

Specs:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600

GPU: AMD RX 560

RAM: 1x8GB DDR4 @2666MHz

120GB SSD & 1TB HDD

MB: Gigabyte GA-A320M-H

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.